Sanjey diagram with variable width
I would like to render a graphic like this:

I thought that Sankey diagram is what is for create diagram like this and I use https://www.npmjs.com/package/chartjs-chart-sankey
However I cannot indicate different start and end width for each flow with Sankey. For each flow, start width and end width is the same. What I need is different width/weight on the same flow between start and end.


const ctx = document.getElementById('myChart');
const colors = {
  a: 'red',
  b: 'green',
  c: 'blue',
  d: 'gray'
};
const getColor = (key) => colors[key];
const chart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'sankey',
  data: {
    datasets: [{
      label: 'My sankey',
      data: [{
        from: 'a',
        to: 'b',
        flow: 10
      }, {
        from: 'a',
        to: 'c',
        flow: 5
      }, {
        from: 'b',
        to: 'c',
        flow: 10
      }, {
        from: 'd',
        to: 'c',
        flow: 7
      }],
      colorFrom: (c) => getColor(c.dataset.data[c.dataIndex].from),
      colorTo: (c) => getColor(c.dataset.data[c.dataIndex].to),
      colorMode: 'gradient', // or 'from' or 'to'
      /* optional labels */
      labels: {
        a: 'Label A',
        b: 'Label B',
        c: 'Label C',
        d: 'Label D'
      },
      priority: {
        b: 1,
        d: 0
      },
      column: {
        d: 1
      },
      size: 'max',
    }]
  },
});
<main style="height: 200px; width: 400px;">
  <canvas id="myChart" style="width: 300px;"></canvas>
</main>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-chart-sankey"></script>



How can I create a graphic like this, and with which library?
For more context :
I would like to make this graphic to display data about product and revenue of a company. Product A is 10% of the sales number (left of the graph above) and makes 40% of the revenue (right of the graph above), product B is 30% of sales number and makes 10% of revenue.

That's not really what a Sankey graph is for as the left and right axes are measuring different values.

So which type of graph is for ?

Probably something like a Percentage chart, but you'll only have 2 points on the X axis. Here's a basic demo: https://jsfiddle.net/4ahp87xz/1/
